# Continuity at a point of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

Let 
$
f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \frac{x}{3} &  x ~\textrm{is rational},\\
    x & x ~\textrm{is irrational}.
  \end{array}
\right.
$

Show that $f$ is continuous at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $a=0$.

My initial approach is to use the sequential criterion with the use of density of rational numbers but I wasn't successful. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in \mathbb R$, $x$ constant. If $(\rho_n)$ be a sequence of rational numbers with $$\lim \rho_n = x \Rightarrow \lim f(\rho_n) = \lim \rho_n/3 = x/3$$
If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of irrational numbers with 
$$\lim a_n = x \Rightarrow \lim f(a_n) = \lim a_n = x$$
then, it is 
$$\lim f(\rho_n)\neq\lim f(a_n) \Leftrightarrow x \neq 0$$
Thus, $f$ is not continuous at $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.

We will now show that $f$ is continuous at $0$. It is $f(0) =0$. For all $|x| < 1$, we have :
$$|f(x) - f(0)| = |f(x)| \leq \max\{|x|,|x|/3\} = |x|$$
thus $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = f(0)$ which means that $f$ is continuous at $0$.